# Кавычки при латинице

Tags: кавычки, латиница-кириллица

Латинские названия в кавычки обычно не заключаются, это я знаю. В кавычки заключаются названия, содержащие оба языка, тоже знаю. Но какие латинские названия всё же нужно заключать в кавычки? Желательно, конечно, назвать все случаи.